# Adwords Dynamic Remarketing for Bidding

Tags: ads, google-ads-api

We have a website like ebay. There is two audience, one is customer and another is store owner.

Store owner adds product so people can bid on it to win.

We have customers, who start bidding on the item once its displaying.

---

Now We want to display `dynamic remarketing ads` to store owners that they have new bids and the highest value is $99 (so its asking store owner to please come back and accept the bid)

**Question**

Is there a way to show latest bids to customer on display network with `dynamic remarketing` on `adwords`?

We want to show these ads only to store owners

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What are bids? You might use dynamic retargeting which I can help you with, but at first I have to know what exactly do you need :). Please, give me some example.

Comment: @KubaChour Thank you for helping out. I have changed the question description completely, please let me know if you need to know something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable, as long as your site doesn't provide bids on AdWords restricted items: https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/6008942?rd=1#con

**But there are some obstacles:**

1. What if owners use AdBlock?
2. click won't be very cheap (my
   rough guess is like 0.5 USD)
3. isn't email for those better option?

**How to do that?**

1) **Make a automaticly refreshed feed** (list) of all provided products and integrate only those, which has value of 99 USD 
(https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6077139?hl=en&ref_topic=6077046)

2) **Set-up Adwords advanced remarketing code** with your product information and id (depends on product) (more on this: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3103357)

3) **In Tag Manager set-up rule of firing AdWords** pixel and add informaion only at sections where store owners set-up or see their products (like site.com/owner-login). This should secure that owners will see only those product which they own.